# Searching for specific beginning pattern in first lines of files only

Tags: linux, shell

I am searching for files containing records that begin with specific pattern but am now running into problems with files (bad data) that contain multiple values in that position within the file, which should never be the case (it should match each record in the file but sometime doesn't). Below is the current code:

```
echo "Parsing out list of warehouses contained in file set."

( cd $DATA && grep -l '^         80' * ) >$TEMP/$program.list.whse80.$$

( cd $DATA && grep -l '^         61' * ) >$TEMP/$program.list.whse61.$$
( cd $DATA && grep -l '^         68' * ) >>$TEMP/$program.list.whse61.$$
( cd $DATA && grep -l '^         69' * ) >>$TEMP/$program.list.whse61.$$

( cd $DATA && grep -l '^         01' * ) >$TEMP/$program.list.whse01.$$
```

.etc...

What is happening is when there is a file containing records records that begin with both the 61 pattern (with preceding 9 spaces) and the 01 pattern, the same filename is being captured in the 61 file and the 01 file. I would like to force only grepping the first line of each file in this manner as I have other logic to catch mixed files later in my program.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Do you want to grep from the first line or do you want the first line with a match?

Comment: I ONLY want to grep the first line of each file.

Answer (score 0):

use head to restrict to top n lines only, for example

```
head -3 file | grep ...
```

for globbing files you can do in a for loop

```
for f in *; do if [ -f "$f" ]; then head -1 "$f" | grep ...; fi; done
```

If you want to output the file name, this solution is not going to work since head just extracts the first line.  However, you can check for grep status and report the file name yourself.

```
if grep -q pattern; then echo $f fi
```

Alternatively you can use awk instead of grep

```
for f in *; do if [ -f "$f" ]; then awk 'NR==1 && /pattern/{print FILENAME}' "$f"; fi; done
```

replace pattern with your pattern.

Comment: for f in *; do if [ -f $f ]; then head -1 $f | grep '^         61'; fi; done

Comment: I get the correct hit but it actually giving me the first like itself, I want the filenames. When I use "grep -l" it blows-up.

Comment: Yahtzee!!!  The awk solution provided above by Karakfa worked perfectly, thanks much...you are the man. Thanks also Walter A for the dircetion, much appreciated...this website is by far the best technical resource out there.